# error in importing scss in React Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass

Hi I am getting this error when trying to import sass-loader.

> ERROR in
>   ./~/css-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./src/styles/main.scss
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   '../../static/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.woff2' in
>   'D:\KumarYa1\Workplace\React\git_react\ReactApp\src\styles'  @
>   ./~/css-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./src/styles/main.scss
>   6:1027-1079  @ ./src/styles/main.scss  @ ./renderer.js

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: "./renderer.js",
  output: {
    filename: "public/bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/, 
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }
      },
      {
test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
        },

      {
        test   : /\.css$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader']
      }, 
      {
        test   : /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'resolve-url-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think `loaders` should be `use`, instead.

Comment: "loaders" where ? I did not get. Can you please be little more specific.

Comment: `test: /.../ , use: [...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please try to add a resolve-url to scss loader?

```
...
{
   test: /\.scss$/,
   loader: 'style!css!sass!resolve-url!sass?sourceMap'
}
...
```

Comment: I am getting this error after doing what you sked.  ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader?sourceMap!./~/extract-text-webpack-plugin/loader.js?{"omit":1,"extract":true,"remove":true}!./~/style-loader!./~/css-loader!./~/sass-loader!./src/styles/main.scss
Module build failed:
@import 'variables';
^
      Invalid CSS after "...load the styles": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi"
      in D:\KumarYa1\Workplace\React\git_react\ReactApp\src\styles\main.scss (line 1, column 1)
 @ ./src/styles/main.scss 4:14-437
 @ ./renderer.js